# Apache HTACCESS routing with Codeigniter under what appears to be a root level folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have an interesting issue that I can't seem to get through. We have a URL that has been setup to route all requests to that URL (via nginx on another server) to my Codeigniter app (that exists on another server). For example, the URL is like this:

http://www.site.com/myappname/controller/function/parameter

Under normal conditions in Codeigniter, it routes the first element after the trailing forward slash to a controller class, then the second to a function within the class, and the third/etc as paramaters of that function.

What I need it to do is to disregard the "myappname" in the URL and have it send through the URL without that. The "myappname" is NOT a folder on the server.

I'm not 100% sure if I need to add new HTACCESS rules, or if I can do this programmatically through Codeigniter.

My current HTACCESS file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt|public|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is a basic, and straight forward HTACCESS setup for all Codeigniter apps, however, using this, and using the structure above, if I go to, http://www.site.com/myappname, with "http://www.site.com/myappname" set as my base_url in the Codeigniter config, Codeigniter then translates it as:

```
http://www.site.com/myappname/myappname
```

So...can anyone help? I also tried to add the following code to the top of my config/routes.php file:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_ireplace('/verified', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

That actually works partially, but now when I request CSS/JS files, from the root, it doesn't pull those in correctly because I use the built in site_url() function to build dynamic links based on the site's "base_url" property. I don't think I can do this 100% programmatically inside Codeigniter (through overwriting system level functions) because my CSS/JS/etc exist in a /public folder in the root of my app (that's obviously excluded from routing via my RewriteCond).

Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) to your `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myappname/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt|public|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Nope...that doesn't appear to do anything. :-/

Comment: `RewriteBase /` give it a try.